# How can we find a vector's decomposition into its pieces in complementary subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be some subspace of a vector space $V$. Then there exists another subspace $T$ so that $V = S\oplus T$, so that $T$ is a "complementary" subspace to $S$. By this, we mean that every $v \in V$ has a unique expression as a sum $v = v_s + v_t$ with $v_s \in S$ and $v_t \in T$.

Say I have a vector $v \in V$ (with $V$ $n$-dimensional over a field $F$) and complementary subspaces $S$ and $T$ so $V = S \oplus T$. How can I figure out $v_s$ and $v_t$ so $v = v_s + v_t$?

Let's assume we have a basis $B = B_s \cup B_t$ for $V$ where $B_s$ is a basis for $S$ and $B_t$ is a basis for $T$. Then we can write $v$ as:
$$
v = a_1b_1 + \cdots + a_n b_n
$$
with each $a_i \in F$ and each $b_i \in B$. Then each $b_i$ is either in $S$ or in $T$ and so we can write $v$ as:
$$
v = \sum_{b_i \in B_s} a_i b_i + \sum_{b_i \in B_t} a_i b_i = v_s + v_t.
$$
If the basis $B$ is orthonormal with respect to some inner product (so $\langle b_i, b_j \rangle = \delta_{ij}$), then by taking dot products against each $b_i$, we can recover each $a_i$, and thereby construct $v_s$ and $v_t$. That is, to find the coefficient $a_i$ we can take the dot product of $v$ against $b_i$. Once we have all the coefficients, then we can form $v_s = \sum_{b_i \in B_s} a_i b_i$ and $v_t =  \sum_{b_i \in B_t} a_i b_i$.

What if the basis $B = B_s \cup B_t$ is not orthonormal? We could then use the Gram–Schmidt process to make it orthonormal, but we will run into a problem. In general $S$ and $T$ are not going to be orthogonal spaces (so we don't have that $\langle s,t \rangle = 0$ for all $s \in S$ and $t \in T$). If $S$ and $T$ aren't orthogonal, then any orthonormal basis for $V$ can't be split up into components $B_s$ and $B_t$ that are bases for $S$ and $T$ respectively. This is because if such a partition were possible, it would imply that $S$ and $T$ were orthogonal, which is a contradiction.

What can we do in the case where $S$ and $T$ aren't orthogonal? Are we stuck for good (is the probably inherently hard computation-wise?)? Is there maybe something we can do that will give an approximate solution, perhaps especially in the case where $\langle v_s, v_t \rangle$ is not too large for normalized $v$?

EDIT 1: As pointed out in the comments, it suffices to find a projection $\rho_{S,T}$ that projects onto $S$ along $T$, so that $\rho_{S,T}(v_s + v_t) = v_s$. Then we can find $v_s$ by applying $\rho_{S,T}$ and find $v_t$ as $v_t = v - v_s$. If $B = B_s \cup B_t$ is a basis for $V$, and $B_s$ and $B_t$ are bases for $S$ and $T$ respectively, we desire $\rho_{S,T}(b_t) = 0$ with $b_t \in B_t$ and $\rho_{S,T}(b_s) = b_s$ with $b_s \in B_s$. We can then extend the definition of $\rho_{S,T}$ to all of $V$ by using linearity.

In practice, we need to introduce a coordinate system to perform these calculations on a computer. We can introduce an ordered basis $(B_s, B_t)$, where $B_s$ and $B_t$ are now ordered bases for $S$ and $T$ respectively. Let $n_s$ be the dimension of $S$ and $n_t$ be the dimension of $T$. Then, in this basis, the matrix representation of $\rho_{S,T}$ will be a diagonal matrix starting with $n_s$ 1's from the top left and then ending with $n_t$ 0's.

To apply the operator $\rho_{S,T}$, we need to represent our vector $v$ is this basis. I assume that a representation of the vector $v$ is available in some basis $C$, so we have $[v]_C$. We then can use the change of basis matrix from $C$ to $B$, $M_{C,B}$, which has the property that $[v]_B = M_{C,B}[v]_C$. Applying this change of basis matrix to $[v]_C$ will yield $[v]_B$, whereupon we can apply $[\rho_{S,T}]_B$. Finally, we apply $(M_{C,B})^{-1}$ to get $[v_s]_C$.

EDIT 2: Note: The above solution requires us to be able to write the vector $v$ in some basis. Unfortunately, in my particular problem, I do not in fact have $v$ in a basis for $V$, but rather I have $v$ represented in a basis for some larger space $U$ containing $V$. However, perhaps this problem should be considered in a separate question.

Comment: It’s not very hard to come up with a projection onto $S$ such that its kernel is $T$, i.e., project onto $S$ “parallel to” $T$. In a suitable basis, the matrix of this projection is $\operatorname{diag}(1,\dots,1,0,\dots,0)$. Think about what basis this might be.

Comment: Thanks @amd. I tried to implement this in an edit - does this look ok to you?